# Xcode 1 Check multiple UIbuttons if they are hidden and If - 2 Sum multiple UIbuttons.title and If

Tags: user-interface

I would like to make these two statement in XCODE.

1- Create a one statement Void/Ibaction/Nsarray... to Check multiple UIbuttons, and if they are =hidden, insert condition if... / 
Example_ If b1,b2,b3... is hidden them uilabel=” is hidden”

2-Sum multiple uibuttons.(Value number in title) and insert condition if...
Example_ if the b1+b2+b3+b4 = "35" them uilabel=”OK Total”

Thanks in advance for you Help.

Edit.